# How to use getchar() with string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, getchar

I try to get a text attached to the array but this does not seem to work when I try to use `printf` after. It does print a blank space.

```
char text[10][30];      // 10 is text count and 30 text length
printf("Enter text: ");
text[0]=getchar();
```

Comment: `text[10][30];` that's not a declaration. [mcve] please

Comment: sorry i meant char text[10][30]

Comment: you cannot put a `char` in a `char *` like this. Do you mean `text[0][0]` ? you'd need to nul terminate as well

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function you are using. Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)..). [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: `getchar()` returns a character, not a text.

Comment: @freestyle not quite. `getchar()` returns an `int` so it can return `EOF` (but that's nitpicking here)

Comment: You might want to use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: As mentioned, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns a single character. `text[0]` is an *array* of characters.

Comment: or `scanf("%29s",text[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution to do what you want. Since your length is a fixed 30, fgets is a good candidate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char text[10][30];

    printf("Input\n");

    fgets(text[0], sizeof(text[0]), stdin);

    printf("%s\n", text[0]);
}
```

Comment: Why ten rows in the matrix when only one is used?  It would be better to use `char text[30];`.  Also, it is sensible to use `fgets(text[0], sizeof(text[0]), stdin);` if you keep the current definition.  And the return value from `fgets()` should be checked before the data is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am just trying to use as much of his initial code as possible. I'm assuming there was a reason he wanted 10 strings. You are correct in using sizeof and checking the return value. I didn't want to open up another can of worms for OP.

Comment: What you can do (what I tend to do) is keep close to the original code, but comment on some of the things that should be changed.  The test for valid input is more nearly critical — I'd make that change anyway: `if (fgets(text[0], sizeof(text[0]), stdin) != NULL) printf("%s\n", text[0]);`.  If the input is short enough, there'll be two newlines in the output; I probably wouldn't bother to mention that.